# No package mysql-community *5.7*

Tags: centos, mysql

I am very new to Cent Os. I have to install mysql on my cent os 6.9 version.

I have tried almost all commands,But am getting one or the other issue while installing.

`yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm`

if i use above command am getting **Nothing to do**

I know there are many answers,But none of the commands helping me to solve this.

Can someone please help me with this issue and to install mysql 5.* version on centos 6.9.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do usually means it is already installed or it did not find the correct rpm file. 
Add -v to see more info. 
You can also use 'yum install '

Comment: i have checked the correct rpm and gave..No it is not installed yet

Comment: Can you please give me correct rpm for Centos 6.9

Comment: `yum install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm` worked for me.

Comment: same am getting `Nothing to do`

Comment: can you check if you have outside network connection? also check `rpm -qa|grep mysql` to see if it installed or not.

Comment: i have added image of `rpm -qa|grep mysql`... i found some info regarding mysql there. can you please check

Comment: looks like you have another version mysql installed. so you need to check if you have use that. And also make sure you tried "yum install" not "localinstall".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72284/discussion-between-hema-and-tux-dev-null).

Comment: sorry, cannot come to the chat now.  I am still not sure about this nothing to install message. Try `yum clean all`. then another install. Other if you can verify that you have another version of mysql installed then try to start the service. Type `which mysql` to see if shows a path.

Comment: am getting `no mysql` in /usr/local/bin